# How to pass parameter to controller function

Tags: c#, jquery, razor, model-view-controller

So I have a form like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm<DataController>("SetYear", null, new { @id = "yearDropdown" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <select id="Year" name="Year" class="form-control">

            @if (objModel.Annums != null)
            {
                foreach (Int32 intYear in objModel.Annums.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList())
                {
                    <option 
                        @if (intYear == DateTime.Now.Year) 
                        { 
                            <text>selected</text> 
                        } 
                        value="@intYear">
                        @intYear
                    </option>
                }
            }

        </div>
    </div>
}
```

And a bit of `jQuery` that submits the form on change (**I realise this can just be done inline**):

```
if ($("#yearDropdown").length) {
    $("#Year").on('change', function () {
        $("#yearDropdown").submit();
    });
}
```

What I want to do, is pass the `Year` to a function in the controller like this:

```
public void SetYear (Int32 intYear)
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Year"] = intYear;
}
```

Can this be done with just C# or will I have to append a `querystring` onto the form URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method in your controller should be an Action and it should return an ActionResult:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SetYear (Int32 intYear)
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Year"] = intYear;
    return View();
}
```

Also, the `Select` element name must match the parameter name of the Action method (`intYear`):

```
@using (Html.BeginUmbracoForm<DataController>("SetYear", null, new { @id = "yearDropdown" }))
{
    <div class="form-group">
        <select id="Year" name="intYear" class="form-control">

            @if (objModel.Annums != null)
            {
                foreach (Int32 intYear in objModel.Annums.OrderByDescending(x => x).ToList())
                {
                    <option 
                        @if (intYear == DateTime.Now.Year) 
                        { 
                            <text>selected</text> 
                        } 
                        value="@intYear">
                        @intYear
                    </option>
                }
            }

        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: I thought it would be something to do with the element name, thanks for the help!